# Let $A$ and $B$ be bounded sets for which $|a-b|\ge \alpha$ for $\alpha >0$ and $a \in A, b \in B$. Show that $m^*(A \cup B)= m^*(A) + m^*(B)$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Let $A$ and $B$ be bounded sets for which $|a-b|\ge \alpha$ for $\alpha >0$ and $a \in A, b \in B$. Show that $m^*(A \cup B)= m^*(A) + m^*(B)$.

The equality $m^*(A \cup B)= m^*(A) + m^*(B)$ holds when $A$ and $B$ are disjoint from countable additivity of disjoint sets. So the task seems to be to show that $A$ and $B$ are disjoint when this property $|a-b|\ge \alpha$ holds.

Suppose the contrary that $A$ and $B$ aren't disjoint. Then there is an $x \in A \cap B$.

Now since $x \in A$ we have that $|x-a| \le \ell(A)$ for any $a \in A$ and likewise since $x \in B$ we have that $|x - b| \le \ell(B)$ for any $b \in B$. (Here $\ell(X)$ is the length of $X$.)

Now from $|x-a| \le \ell(A)$ we have that $$a-\ell(A)<x<\ell(A)+a$$

and from $|x-b| \le \ell(B)$ we have that $$b-\ell(B)<x<\ell(B)+b.$$

How can I argue from here that $x$ is in two disjoint sets in order to strive a contradiction? It seems that I should use the fact that $|a-b| \le \alpha$ somehow, but I don't have any $|a-b|$ terms here?

Edit:

Would the triangle inequality help if I look at $$|x-(a-b)| \ge |x|-|a-b| \ge|x|-\alpha?$$

Comment: Isn't it much simpler? If $x \in A \cap B$ then $0 = |x-x| \ge \alpha > 0$ violates the given condition.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4254832/42969.

Comment: I suppose $|x-x| = 0 $ would satisfy this. Seems a bit too simple to work, but I cannot come up why it wouldn't?

Comment: Note that formulation of the statement is not very clear. What you need is that there is a $\alpha > 0$ with the property that  $|a-b| \ge \alpha$ for *all* $a \in A$ and all $b \in B$. That clearly implies that the sets are disjoint.